# Connect to private RDS in AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, vpc, private-subnet

I want to test a **Docker container** that run with a DB connection. That DB is a **RDS DB instance** in AWS but it is in a **private VPC subnet**.

[image]

Is possible to connect to a RDS DB instance that is in a private VPC Subnet from my computer? Using a SQL Client or with AWS CLI like the image:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to connect directly to instances in private subnets on AWS for obvious security reasons.

However there are multiple ways to achieve this connection:

- Setup a [VPN](https://openvpn.net/amazon-cloud/) in you VPC. The VPN would be publicly accessible and would allow your computer to communicate with private instances.
- Setup a [bastion host](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html).Then create an [SSH tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) to your RDS instance with something like this:

  ```
  ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3306:rds-endpoint:3306 bastion-publi-ip
  ```

The first solution is more interesting if you want to access multiple RDS at the same time because you won't have to setup multiple SSH tunnels. The VPN could be setup manually on an EC2 to reduce the pricing.

The second solution is easier to deploy and more cost effective.

Comment: But the second one does not allow me to access a web, only to the instance.